# How do you stop a soundeffect once it starts?

Tags: apache-flex

Objective:  Play a sound effect when the user mouses down on the HSlider.  Stop or pause the sound when the user mousses up.  The following code starts the sound but a mouseup does not stop it.

```
<mx:SoundEffect id="soundEffectSong" useDuration="false" source="http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/sound/song1.mp3"/>
<mx:Form x="10" y="39" width="454" height="452">
    <mx:FormItem label="Age">
        <mx:HSlider id="ageSlider" allowTrackClick="true" minimum="1" maximum="100" snapInterval="1" liveDragging="true" value="1" mouseDownEffect="{soundEffectSong}" mouseUpEffect="{soundEffectSong.pause()}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the end() method instead of pause()?

So:

```
... mouseUpEffect="{soundEffectSong.end()}"/>
```

Documentation for [end()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/Effect.html#end()) says:

> Interrupts an effect that is currently playing, and jumps immediately to the end of the effect.

Comment: Yes...Tried that as well. Same result.  Effect keeps playing.